# Convert multidimensional array to a simple array by recursion

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

How to convert this array:

```
$array = [
    "order" => [
        "items" => [
            "6" => [
                "ndc" => "This value should not be blank."
            ],
            "7" => [
                "ndc" => "This value should not be blank."
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

to

```
$array = [
    "order[items][6][ndc]" => "This value should not be blank.",
    "order[items][7][ndc]" => "This value should not be blank.",
];
```

First array may have unlimited number of nested levels. So nested foreach is not an option.

I spent a lot of time searching for the solution and got nothing. Can, please, someone help or guide me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do the job :

```
$newArr = [];

function reduce_multi_arr($array, &$newArr, $keys = '') {
  if (!is_array($array)) {
      $newArr[$keys] = $array;
  } else {
      foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        if ($keys === '') $nextKey = $key; // first key
        else $nextKey = '[' . $key . ']'; // next [keys]
        reduce_multi_arr($val, $newArr, $keys . $nextKey);
      }
  }
}

reduce_multi_arr($array, $newArr);

print_r($newArr);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [order[items][6][ndc]] => 'This value should not be blank.'
    [order[items][7][ndc]] => 'This value should not be blank.'
)
```

Comment: Oh my god. You're really awesome. Thank you a lot!